# Loading Selenium Page Objects Based on Browser Window Size

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, pageobjects

We are building a web application that has expandable workspaces on the sides of the page that expand and contract based on page size. when the workplace is contracted the page objects of the expanded list are not visible to be initialized when the class is called as the site is being developed in Angular 2.0

We are also building an automated test framework with Selenium with C# bindings and using the Page Object Model to run our automation. Is it possible load objects based on the window into a single page class like this

```
public class PageObjectClass
{
    public PageObjectClass(IwebDriver driver)
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this)
    }

    private IWebElement anObjectVisibleWhenContracted
    //load an object that is not visible based on window size
}
```

Or do I need to get the size of the window when I call the class and have separate classes based on window width in the test scripts like this?

```
if (driver.Manage().Window.Size.Width < 1280)
{
    someVar = new PageObjectClass(driver):
}
else
{
    someOtherVar = new exp[andedPageObjects
}
//do stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to face issues when an element is displayed but Selenium doesn't interact with it a good practice is to maximize your browser's window on setUp.

Still if you don't want to do this, Selenium scrolls to an element when you interact with it.

**So, answering your question** - you don't need to change the window size. When you use PageObject in C# like you shown then each element will be initialized when you address to it (click, sendKeys, etc.). Each time you address to an element it will be initialized again and Selenium must scroll to this element.

But there are some bugs that appears in some cases when an element is displayed at the edge of the page and Selenium can not scroll to it correctly. Why this happens I don't know but luckily it happens very rarely.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on my own. In the classes where I needed to deal with expandable workspaces, I declared all my variables in the class and didn't assign them any values before running PageFactory.InitElements

In the class constructor I passed in a Size variable along with the WebDriver that has the current size of the window. Then the objects that were appropriate for the window size were all loaded based on that

Just took a little restructuring and now it's working like a charm. Class structure looks like this now

```
public class ClassName: InheritedClass
{

    #region Page Objects

    private IWebElement object1;
    private IWebElement object2;

    #endregion

    public ClassName(IWebDriver driver, Size winSize)
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);

        if (winSize.Width > 1440)
        {
            object1= driver.FindElement(expanded By phrase locator);
            object1 = driver.FindElement(expanded By phrase locator);
        }
        else
        {
            object1= driver.FindElement(contracted By phrase locator);
            object1 = driver.FindElement(contracted By phrase locator);
        }
    }

    #region Page Methods that use these objects
    #endregion
}
```